# Is this implementation of insertion in array incorrect?

Tags: c, arrays

I was reading a tutorial at tutorialspoint.com for [Data Structures](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/array_data_structure.htm). 
In the section about the array data structure is this implementation of insertion an element in an array, which is accesing an element outside of the bound of the array  :

```
   int LA[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
   int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
   int i = 0, j = n;

   printf("The original array elements are :\n");

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
   }

   n = n + 1;

   while( j >= k){
      LA[j+1] = LA[j];
      j = j - 1;
   }

   LA[k] = item;

   printf("The array elements after insertion :\n");

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
   }
```

Is'nt accesing an element outside of the bounds of an array undefined behaviour and therefore very bad practice? 
If so why is this given in a tutorial?

Comment: Yes it is. Who knows, was is an example of how not to do it?

Comment: It doesn't seem so.:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/array_data_structure.htm

Comment: Tutorialspoint is a very poor resource. I'd recommend [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) for C and C++ stuff.

Comment: That's pretty horrible that they have that online...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is'nt accesing an element outside of the bounds of an array undefined behaviour

Yes.  Good spotting.

> and therefore very bad practice?

I can't argue with that, except maybe to say that it's a little understated.  A program that exhibits UB is flat ***wrong***.

> If so why is this given in a tutorial?

I can only speculate, but that section of the tutorial is not only wrong, but altogether poorly conceived.  C arrays have fixed length, therefore you cannot "insert" into a C array in any sense that preserves all the values that already were there.  (I disregard dynamic memory approaches, which are not relevant to the code presented.)

You *can* use code similar to that presented in the example if you adjust it to avoid reading or writing past the end of the array. Such an approach to "inserting" an element must lose the element originally at the array's end.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's a bad practice. When you try to do

```
   while( j >= k){
      LA[j+1] = LA[j];
      j = j - 1;
   }
```

... you will have LA[6] receiving a value when LA has size 5. Then an error message will be shown and at some moment the execution will be aborted. Besides that the exit status (echo $?) will be different of zero, i.e., it is saying that your program wasn't finished with successful.